# Hide search results until load and then fadeIn?

Tags: jquery, fadein

This code below fades out the first results then fades in too early an the next results just appear anyway

```
$('.content .sub_cont').load('superfetch.php?val=' + $('.searchInput').val(), hideLoader(function() { $(this).fadeIn(1500); }));
```

Comment: @why negative voting for the above question ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
$('.content .sub_cont').load('superfetch.php?val=' + $('.searchInput').val(), hideLoader(function() { $(this).delay(1500).fadeIn(1500); }));
```

Comment: I figured that would do but, Its not actually strapping it to the load time, oh well

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
$('.content .sub_cont').hide(0);
$.get('superfetch.php?val=' + $('.searchInput').val(), function(data){
    $('.content .sub_cont').html(data);
    $('.content .sub_cont').hide(0); //Sometimes it will show it when changing the HTML
    $('.content .sub_cont').fadeIn(1500);
});
```